# CSS keep footer at bottom , failed sticky footer

Tags: css, footer, sticky-footer

My footer will not stay at the bottom of my page.
I tried the sticky footer trick, but no good.

Seems my footer has white space beneath it.
Adjusting height on it has done no good.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style3.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="navigation.js"></script>
    </head><body>


<div id="top">



<header>
    <div id="topLeft">topleft</div>
    <nav id="nav-wrap">

    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Attendees</a><ul><li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li><li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li><li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li><li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li></ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Exhibitors</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Speakers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Program</a></li>

    </ul>

</nav>
<div id="topRight">topright</div>
</header>

</div>  

<div id="middle">
<div id="headerLeft"></div>
<div id="headerimage">
    <img src="header-2013.jpg"/>
    </div>

<div id="headerRight"></div>    
    <br style="clear: left;" />

</div>

<div id="pagewrap"> 











<div id="content">
        <!-- <h3>To see the mobile navigation, narrow your browser window or check with a mobile device.</h3>
        <p>Unholy is a new, upcoming raiding guild with goals of
successfully accomplishing Player versus Environment and Player versus Player
raiding content. If thou art seeking such guild then thou would consider joining
us on our quest to victory over the evils that lurk within the depths of
Karazhan and Zul'Aman. All are welcome that have experienced the foul beasts
that roam abroad the forsaken ground in the Outlands and whish to further
explore and cleanse such places. If this should be thy calling then we welcome
you to our quest for victory, For the Horde </p> -->
        </div>






</div>

<footer>
<div id="footer">
footer
</div>
</footer>
</body></html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
/************************************************************************************
GENERAL
*************************************************************************************/
html{
        height:auto;
    }

body {
    font: .9em/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    overflow-x:hidden;

    /******extra Mike Clayton **/
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;  
    height:100%;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #39C;
}
h1, h2 {
    line-height: 120%;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    color: #000;
}
header {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}


/************************************************************************************
STRUCTURE
*************************************************************************************/
#pagewrap {
     width: 100%;
     max-width:650px;
    margin: 0px auto;

    /**Mike Clayton**/
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#content {
    clear: both;
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    width:100%;

    /**Mike clayton**/
    /* padding-bottom:250px; */
    padding-bottom:55%;
}



#top{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#002664;
    clear:both;
    }


#topLeft{
    float:left;
    background-color:#002664;
    width:20%;
    margin:0;
    }   

#topRight{
    float:left;
    background-color:#002664;
    width:20%;
    margin:0;
    }


#middle{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#AD1B30;
    overflow: hidden;

    }   
#headerLeft{
    float:left;
    background-color:#AD1B30;
    width:20%;
    margin:0;

}   

#headerimage{
        width:650px;
        align:center;
        margin:0 auto;


}

#headerimage img{
    width:100%;
    }

#headerRight{
    float:left;
    background-color:#AD1B30;
    width:20%;
    margin:0;
}   

#footer{
/*  background-color:#002664;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:-100;
    height:150px; */

    clear: both;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
 height: 3em;
 margin-top: -3em;
 background-color:#002664;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:-100;

}
/************************************************************************************
NAV
*************************************************************************************/
#nav-wrap {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/* menu icon */
#menu-icon {
    display: none; /* hide menu icon initially */
}

#nav, 
#nav li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

/* nav link */
#nav a {
    padding: 4px 15px;
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    background: #ecebeb;
}
#nav a:hover {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

/* nav dropdown */
#nav ul {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    display: none; /* hide dropdown */
    width: 200px;
}
#nav ul li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block; /* show dropdown on hover */
}

/************************************************************************************
MOBILE
*************************************************************************************/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    /* nav-wrap */
    #nav-wrap {
        position: relative;
    }

    /* menu icon */
    #menu-icon {
        color: #000;
        width: 42px;
        height: 30px;
        background: #ecebeb url(menu-icon.png) no-repeat 10px center;
        padding: 8px 10px 0 42px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: solid 1px #666;
        display: block; /* show menu icon */
    }
    #menu-icon:hover {
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
    }
    #menu-icon.active {
        background-color: #bbb;
    }

    /* main nav */
    #nav {
        clear: both;
        position: absolute;
        top: 38px;
        width: 160px;
        z-index: 10000;
        padding: 5px;
        background: #f8f8f8;
        border: solid 1px #999;
        display: none; /* visibility will be toggled with jquery */
    }
    #nav li {
        clear: both;
        float: none;
        margin: 5px 0 5px 10px;
    }
    #nav a, 
    #nav ul a {
        font: inherit;
        background: none;
        display: inline;
        padding: 0;
        color: #666;
        border: none;
    }
    #nav a:hover, 
    #nav ul a:hover {
        background: none;
        color: #000;
    }

    /* dropdown */
    #nav ul {
        width: auto;
        position: static;
        display: block;
        border: none;
        background: inherit;
    }
    #nav ul li {
        margin: 3px 0 3px 15px;
    }

    #headerimage {
        display: none;
    }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

    /* ensure #nav is visible on desktop version */
    #nav {
        display: block !important;
    }

}
```

---

So, that last post from Kakarott worked.

Also, I used position:relative for my Media Query mobile dev and it made that same CSS work for my Mobile site.

So, for desktop and tablet, I'm using position:absolute and for mobile:relative.

FYI, I'm using a responsive design.

Answer (score 3):

Check this

http://code.google.com/p/cleanstickyfooter/

and the best solution

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: Yep, use CSSstickyfooter.com.  I used that on my website and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Change your footer css to:

```
#footer{

 clear: both;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
 height: 3em;
 bottom:0;
 background-color:#002664;
 width:100%;


}
```

Comment: Absolute will only position it near the bottom of the viewport.  So if you have more content and you scroll vertically, the footer is stuck in that same spot.

Comment: perfect, 2 seconds and it's working! Do I have to close out this question?

Comment: Your css is pretty messed up. You have to make many changes to making it work in every kind if machine and browser.

Comment: So, that last post from Kakarott worked.

Also, I used position:relative for my Media Query mobile dev and it made that same CSS work for my Mobile site.

So, for desktop and tablet, I'm using position:absolute and for mobile:relative.

FYI, I'm using a responsive design.

Comment: true it is a bit messy, but so far it's working in all browser I need: FF,Chrome,IE,Android,iPhone,iPad